# CSS3 Slide Show Fade Effect not working

Tags: javascript, css, fadein, fadeout

http://jsfiddle.net/pdb4kb1a/2/

The code works just fine on JSFiddle, but I cant get it to work when I use it in a HTML/CSS file. Only the 50x200 image is displayed, no signs of the simple slideshow or fade effect. I work in Sublime text, could that create any problems?

```js
var imgArray = [
    'http://placehold.it/300x200',
    'http://placehold.it/200x100',
    'http://placehold.it/400x300'],
    curIndex = 0;
    imgDuration = 3000;

function slideShow() {
    document.getElementById('slider').className += "fadeOut";
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('slider').src = imgArray[curIndex];
        document.getElementById('slider').className = "";
    },1000);
    curIndex++;
    if (curIndex == imgArray.length) { curIndex = 0; }
    setTimeout(slideShow, imgDuration);
}
slideShow();
```

```css
#slider {
    opacity:1;
    transition: opacity 1s; 
}

#slider.fadeOut {
    opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<body> 
<img id="slider" src="http://placehold.it/50x200">
</body>
```

Comment: Does the console show any errors? Show us the `HTML` file you made?

Comment: Here it seems like its working fine. How do you include the JavaScript in your HTML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSFiddle executes the javascript code in the `window.onload` event. You can change this if you click the JavaScript Button in the editor of JSFiddle.
If you change it to `No wrap - in <head>` you'll see that it doesn't work as well. You should see an error in your console, telling you the reason.

I'm assuming that you're including your script snippet in the `head` section of your HTML Document.

If you take your code as posted in your question, your `slider` isn't loaded yet, because the script is executed before your HTML document is fully loaded. You have to wrap the call to your `slideShow` function inside the `onload`event (or if you're using `jQuery` you'll probably use `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })` instead.

This should do the trick then:

```
window.onload = function() {
    slideShow();
}
```

Including the script at the bottom of your HTML document should work as well as an alternative.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. It didn't make a difference wether it was in the <head> or <body>, it got the same results!

Comment: You're welcome. At the end of your body? Mh that's odd. Works in your fiddle as well if you set the script to be included in the body.